# Updating existing unencrypted records with attr_encrypted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, attr-encrypted

How do I update existing records that were previously unencrypted with the gem attr_encrypted.

I currently have the column `text` in a table called `AppointmentNote` which is just a string. I now want to have a column called `note` which is encrypted (with attr_encrypted).

I've added the columns

`encrypted_note`
`encrypted_note_iv`

This works well when I do `AppointmentNote.create(note: "blah")` it encrypts properly, and any further updates on that record work well.

The problem is with records created prior to the migration. How do i migrate all the data from the column `text` into the new encrypted columns `encrypted_note` and `encrypted_note_iv`

This is the model

```
class AppointmentNote < ApplicationRecord
  attr_encrypted_options.merge!(encode: true)
  attr_encrypted :note, key: SOME_KEY
  ...
end
```

If i do the what I thought the obvious solution was it simply roll back
`AppointmentNote.first.update(note: "rawr")`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just update them all with a save. Something like:

`rails g migration update_apartment_notes_note_for_encryption`

Open that generated file.

```
def change
  AppointmentNote.find_each do |apartment_note|
    apartment_note.save 
  end
end
```

`rake db:migrate`

Note: Using find_each is wiser than `all` if you have tons of records. The goal here is to iterate over them.

Comment: Thanks, I think my issue was having messed up records in my database. This kind've helped out some of those.